# How to login webmail with Python?

Tags: python

```
import requests

import webbrowser

s=requests.session()

login_data = dict(email='email', password= 'password')

s.post("https://www.otoservisbul.com/tr/login", data=login_data)

r = requests.post('https://www.otoservisbul.com/tr/login', data = {'email':'password'})

webbrowser.get(using='chrome').open("https://www.otoservisbul.com/tr/items/list")
```

Hi , 
Here is my python code. I try to login my webmail via code. When I run this code login page is openning with Google Chrome but couldn't wrote the username and password. I know there have been a lot of entries about this topic but I really couldn't find the problem.

Comment: You don't pass the args to webbrowser.

Comment: You do not say what is the webmail. Many should reject your login attempt because they will detect a [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)...

Comment: @Kingname can you please check?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta I try another website. You could see above. Still it is not working :(

Comment: Oups! This is an Ajax login form... Either try reverse engeneering on the JavaScript, or try to analyze what is exchanged over the network. I can just say that what is exchanged is JSON and the URL is `https://www.otoservisbul.com/api/auth/local`. Good luck if you want to automate an Ajax login form...

Comment: @BekirAydin You have just changed your question. the init version was not like this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you did not pass `login_data`to post request.

```
>>> r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```